# on symmetric positive semi-definiteness of covariance matrices in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, covariance

Hi everybody I have this problem:

- I have Dataset of n vectors each has D dimensions.
- I also have a covariance matrix of size D*D, Let It be C.

I perform the following action:

- I choose K vectors from the dataset, and also choose E dimensions randomly. Let M be the sample covariance of the selected data on the selected dimensions.so M is a E*E matrix.
- let P be the partial covariance matrix corresponding to the dimensions E of C, ie. C(E,E) in matlab

**is the following matrix positive semi definite?:**

**X = (1-a)*P + a*M**

where a is a constant like 0.2.

I sometimes get the following error when using mvnrnd(mean,X) :
SIGMA must be a symmetric positive semi-definite matrix

My code is:

```
%%%Dims are randomly choosen dimensions
%%%Inds are randomly choosen Indexes form {1, 2, ...,n}
%%% PP are n D dimensional vectors, composing my data set PP is n*D
%%% Sigmaa is a D*D covariance matrix
co = cov(PP(Inds,Dims));
me = mean(PP(Inds,Dims));
Bettaa = 0.2;
sigmaaDims = sigmaa(Dims,Dims);
sigmaaDims = (1-Bettaa)*sigmaaDims + (co)*Bettaa;
Tem = mvnrnd(me,sigmaaDims);
```

Comment: Convex (and conical) combinations of positive semi-definite matrices are positive semi-definite (just expand the definition of `X` in `v'Xv`).  So your question boils down to whether the (symmetric) matrices P and M are both positive semidefinite.

Comment: Thank you Ben , But as I said M is sample covariance so it ought to be positive semidefinite. And P is partial matrix obtained from projecting dimensions E form a positive semidefinite matrix. so the question is: is P always positive semidefinit, the second question is if so why matlab keep erroring and how I can prevent this?

Comment: Just to confirm, your constant a is always between 0 and 1, right?

Comment: yes, in fact always 0.2

Comment: I didint understand ur last question well, "you need ALL eigenvalues to be non-negative, not just one?" But, I am not much of math and  I always had problems with eigenvalues ;) but I added my code for further detailes

Comment: Don't worry about that comment, brodroll already corrected his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simply looking at the matrix dimensions It is not possible to tell if a matrix is positive semi-definite.

To find out if a given matrix is [positive semi-definite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Negative-definite.2C_semidefinite_and_indefinite_matrices), you must check if It's eigenvalues are non-negative and it's symmetry:

```
symmetry = issymmetric(X);
[~,D]=eig(X);
eigenvalues = diag(D);
if all(eigenvalues>0) & symmetry
    disp('Positive semi-definite matrix.')
else
     disp('Non positive semi-definite matrix.')
end
```

Where **X** is the matrix you are interested in.

Note that if you use the weaker definition of a positive definite matrix (see *Extention for non symmetric matrices* section), **X** does not need to be symmetric and you would end up with:

```
[~,D]=eig(X);
eigenvalues = diag(D);
if all(eigenvalues>=0)
    disp('Positive semi-definite matrix.')
else
     disp('Non positive semi-definite matrix.')
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. but my problem is: I think X should be positive semi definite, but matlab sometimes gives the error, so how can I prevent this see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269715/matlabs-sigma-must-be-symmetric-and-positive-definite-error-sometimes-not-mak there is a some how similar situation

Comment: I realized I answered the question, but have not given a solution to the problem. @BenVoigt Thanks it should be all, not any.

Comment: I found a good discussion on how to mitigate the problem here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/57411-matlab-sometimes-produce-a-covariance-matrix-error-with-non-postive-semidefinite